# Is it possible to use Android Wireless Display (Miracast) to broadcast something else than a screen mirroring?

Tags: android, network-protocols, wireless, upnp

On my Nexus 4 et 5, the wireless display is working well with a simple Miracast adapter (I use a Tronsmart T1000) to duplicate the mobile screen to my TV.

Now I'd like to develop an application that would use this wireless display to send something else than the pure duplication of the screen display. Something like some games you can find on an iPad using AirPlay. The mobile screen has some kind of commands HMI, while the exported display renders a different view...

Does anybody know if this is technically possible using Miracast ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible. Check out the [Presentation Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html). There are some pretty good examples of how it can be used [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastPresentation-android)

Comment: Confused why I was down voted. If you need additional help I would be happy to provide it. I have quite a bit of experience working with the API.